# Prepared statement execute query error (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException)

Tags: java, mysql, hikaricp

I have written a simple method to get a string out of the database:

```
    public String getUserString(int id, String table, String column) {
    String output = null;
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE id=?;";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, column);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, table);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, id);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            output = resultSet.getString(column);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```

But when I try to use it like this: `coreMySQL.getUserString(1, "economy", "balance");`

I get this error:
https://pastebin.com/BMAmN4Xh

Comment: is you table name is balance? could you provide a snapshot of your  database table

Comment: My table name is not balance, it's economy. Here's a screenshot of the database: https://image.prntscr.com/image/WYs3J5XkT3_oSvK2EI5jfg.png

Comment: remove ';' so "SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE id=?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set table name and column names with `setXxx` method(s) for `PreparedStatement`. It can only be used to set the values.

However, you can do a simple `String` replace to substitute table names and column names, e.g.:

```
String query = SELECT <column> FROM <table> WHERE id=?;
String sql = query.replaceAll("<column>", column).replaceAll("<table>", table);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    output = resultSet.getString(column);
}
```

Comment: @blablamuhaha you can accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: It's my first time on stackoverflow, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Define a query template as:

```
String queryTemplate = "SELECT %s FROM %s where id = ?;";

// Inside Function:

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(String.format(template, column, table));
preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```